# How to replace comma in textbox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I have two textboxes, the textbox1 echo's value from database $row and displays 1,900,200.00 on digit grouping. My textbox2 automatically copies the exact value of textbox1 using javascript. What I want to do is to replace the comma (,) in textbox2.

Comment: replace `,` with what?

Comment: try `document.getElementById('txt2').value = document.getElementById('txt1').value.replace(/,/g, '.');` to replace all instances of `,`

Comment: You've pretty well already [mentioned the core of your answer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) ("*replace*") in the question. So, have you tried it? What result did you get? And, how did that differ from your expectations?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
document.getElementById('txt2').value = document.getElementById('txt1').value.replace(/,/g, '');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function doCombine18() {
    var txt1 = document.getElementById('txt1'),
        txt2 = document.getElementById('txt2');

    txt2.value = txt1.value.split(',').join('');
}
```

It will remove all commas `,`. If you want to replace them with something else, you may to change `.join()` argument.

Comment: +1 for not using `str.replace`

Comment: @opatut, actually I would say it's very counter intuitive and *perhaps even slower* to do it this way over using the `replace` function that is there for that exact purpose. It's not about fiding cool ways to do something, it's about writing clean, simple and efficient code ;)

Comment: @opatut http://jsperf.com/replace-vs-split-join-vs-replaceall/23

Comment: Both methods exists. Yeah, `.replace` is faster. But this one working too. I mean, to use it once doesn't mean to use it everywhere. Ok, now you may say that "It is a bad practice" to say that. Maybe, but how often do you use "dirty" tricks ?

Comment: @plalx That is a neat performace tool there. I actually didn't know `replace` was faster nowadays -- the split-join-trick *used to be* more efficient.